# Change Link with HTML Dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to use the values from an HTML dropdown menu to change the "where" of the Google Spreadsheet query HTML table.

Here's the dropdown as I have it so far:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

And the link I need it to change looks like this (inside of an iframe):

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/*spreadsheet key*/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&tq=select+A,B,D,E,F,G+**where+D+contains+'*CHANGETHIS*'**&gid=2105149734" width="100%" height="200"></iframe>
```

Basically I need `CHANGETHIS` to equal whatever is selected in the dropdown.

Is this possible?

Comment: possible but show whatever you tried.

Comment: This is possible, but have you tried to implement it yourself yet? Users on SO will be reluctant to answer questions without any demonstrated effort by the original poster.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('option').click(function(e){
  var $item = $(e.currentTarget).attr('value');
  updateIframe($('iframe'), $item);
});

function loadIframe(iframeName, url) {
    if ( $iframe.length ) {
        $iframe.attr('src',url);   
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You can also use the `.change()` event.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using javascript. First you need to add id to the select

So change your list to

```
<select id="myID">             <====== heres the change
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
var value = document.getElementById("myID");
var selectedString = value.options[value.selectedIndex].value;
```

here `selectedString` contains the value to be added to the string in IFrame.

```
var Url="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/*spreadsheet key*/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&tq=select+A,B,D,E,F,G+**where+D+contains+selectedString+&gid=2105149734"
```

or use `innerHTML`