# How does one save an HTML dropdown value in a Google Script context?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I have a dropdown menu in an html page. What I do not know how to code is how to save the menu option the user chooses, so that it can be moved into the gs file.

I have looked through the SO site for the code, but all I seem to find are answers involving javascript, php, etc. ([Change Link with HTML Dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126091/change-link-with-html-dropdown) and [Fill HTML dropdown box with external JSON file data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17760866/fill-html-dropdown-box-with-external-json-file-data) for instance).

The test code I am trying to build is below:

## html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
<select id="Instrument">
       <option>1</option>
       <option>2</option>
       <option>3</option>
    </select>

<!--Need code here to save the option chosen above and code that 
allows for the option chosen to be moved to the gs side of this.-->

  </body>
</html>
```

I expect to be able to "save" the option and pass it to the Google script so it can be further manipulated there.

For instance, were I dealing simply with input fields, rather than data from a dropdown, I would write something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>

    <input id="idNewSongTitle" type="text" placeholder="Song Title"><br><br>
    <input id="idNewSongWriters" type="text" placeholder="Song Writers">*<br><br>
    <button onclick="saveUserInput()">Create New Lyric Doc</button></center><br><br>
    <script>
      window.saveUserInput = function() {
        var docName = document.getElementById('idNewSongTitle').value;
        var songTitle = document.getElementById('idNewSongTitle').value;
        var songWriters = document.getElementById('idNewSongWriters').value;
        console.log('songTitle: ' + songTitle)
        google.script.run       
          .withSuccessHandler(openNewDoc)
          .createNewLandscapeLyric({docName:docName,songTitle:songTitle, songWriters: songWriters})
      }
       function openNewDoc(results){
           window.open(results.url, '_blank').focus();
       }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

## Update

OK. Thank you @TheMaster. Now we're cookin'!

I used your 2nd suggestion and put it into a real world version I am working with as follows:

## html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<base target="_top" />
  </head>
  <body>
<select id="InstrNum" name="Instrument Number">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select><br><br>
<button onclick="saveUserInput()">Continue</button><br><br>
    
<script>
   window.saveUserInput = function() {
   var instrNum = document.getElementById('InstrNum').value;
   console.log('instrNum: ' + instrNum)
        google.script.run       
           .withSuccessHandler(openCatalog)
           .insertInfo({instrNum:instrNum})
          
   function openCatalog(results){
           window.open(results.url, '_blank').focus();
       }
}
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

## gs

```
function onCheck(e) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var cell= sheet.getActiveCell().getColumn();
    var col = ss.getRange('Perform').getColumn(); 
        if (cell == col){
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
      .setWidth(400)
      .setHeight(300);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Performance Information');
}
   }
function insertInfo(objArgs){
    var instrNum = objArgs.instrNum;
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var cell= sheet.getActiveCell();
    var oneCellRight = cell.offset(0, 1)
    oneCellRight.setValue(instrNum);

}
```

It does exactly what I expected, except for two issues. (I.e., when I look at the SS, the value from the dropdown menu choice has been entered into the target cell.)

The two things not happening which I need to happen are:

- The dialog box does not close when I click the "Continue" button.
- The Catalog SS is not opened.

Any ideas on that?

## Update 2

As @TheMaster notes, my questions immediately above are unrelated. I took a look at some similar code I have and realized I forgot the return statement. So, I added it as below and it solved one issue: opened up a new Catalog SS.  However, it did not (and apparently one cannot) close the dialog, nor the original open Catalog SS page.

## Revised gs

```
function insertInfo(objArgs){
    var instrNum = objArgs.instrNum;
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var url = ss.getUrl()
    Logger.log(url)
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var cell= sheet.getActiveCell();
    var oneCellRight = cell.offset(0, 1)
    oneCellRight.setValue(instrNum);
    return {
        url: url
  };
```

That concludes this broadcast.

Comment: Your update and the new questions  isn't even related to the original question. It'll be better to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Script Logic:

- `change` event is fired every time the option is changed  and committed in `select`. You can use that to send data to server.
- Alternatively, You can use your saveUserInput function to get the `select`'s value. If you want to enforce some sort of data validation, use `<form>` instead.

#### Snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<base target="_top" />
  </head>
  <body>
<select id="Instrument" name="InstrumentSelect">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>

<!--Code to save the option chosen above and code that 
allows for the option chosen to be moved to the gs side of this.-->
<script>
  handleOptionChange = function(e) {
    console.info(e.target.value);
    google.script.run.optionChanged(e.target.value);
  };
  document
    .getElementById('Instrument')
    .addEventListener('change', handleOptionChange);
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

OR

```
var instrument = document.getElementById('Instrument').value;
```